# Why doesn't typescript infer actual conditional bound type with nested type argument?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

In the following snippet why doesn't typescript infer the actual `F` type as the functions return type, and only infers it as the bound (`GenericPerson`) which doesn't have the 'address' property?

```
type GenericPerson = { name: string; };
type GenericCompany<X extends GenericPerson> = { companyName: string; employees: X[]; };

const getEmployeeDetails= <F extends GenericPerson, T extends GenericCompany<F>>(company: T): F[] => {
  return company.employees;
};

getEmployeeDetails({
  companyName: 'XYZ',
  employees: [
    {
      name: 'John',
      address: 'London',
    }
  ],
}).map((x) => {
  console.log(x.address); // Property 'address' does not exist on type GenericPerson
});
```

[[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgBWQZwPbygF4oBvAKCingEMBbCALim2FXgHMBuMgX27NCRYCZOgDCuWmGrwQAHgAaUCAA9gCACbZhiVJhz4AfEVIUoaSdNkA5Oo2asUHbpQhSANrhAQI2JgoBtAF1uPjIyC3gWKHYIYABRDy8fABE46hR3bGI5ADFlNU1tOF10LCQ8eAAaKAAVAvV4LR1RNAkpGXlcw0MACgsO2SZagEomXOCiY3JKJDiAVyQCAasQADo3ME9vX1D+WISknbTgDKzemfNLTtt6JgByBQBNAC17qrNN7Z8-KACzSiXSiUGh3KD3ABSuAAFvB3gDgdQNBo5thfvcADL4DT4eHAqA8MxBD48EZrWjUMC9XoqEZTUyUSJ4dwQNaedg0tZIlG+bAjUL8oA)]

I can fix it by explicitly providing the type arguments

```
type ExtendedPerson = {name: string; address: string};
getEmployeeDetails<ExtendedPerson, GenericCompany<ExtendedPerson>>({
  companyName: 'XYZ',
  employees: [
    {
      name: 'John',
      address: 'London',
    }
  ],
}).map((x) => {
  console.log(x.address); // Type-checks.
});
```

[[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgBWQZwPbygF4oBvAKCingEMBbCALim2FXgHMBuMgX27NCRYCZOgDCuWmGrwQAHgAaUCAA9gCACbZhiVJhz4AfEVIUoaSdNkA5Oo2asUHbpQhSANrhAQI2JgoBtAF1uPjIyC3gWKHYIYABRDy8fABE46hR3bGI5ADFlNU1tOF10LCQ8eAAaKAAVAvV4LR1RNAkpGXlcw0MACgsO2SZagEomXOCiY3JKJDiAVyQCAasQADo3ME9vX1D+QWh4wqaIDXLKkxIaeiYWNi4oag0NOew-B3uw2ISknbTgDJZORHRoaU7nfA1EqtdqrYHHMFnAzwHq9GbmSydWw3KAAcgUAE0AFq4qpmTbbHzvAJmSjoyiUa72XEAKVwAAt4KTaQyni9fO9cQAZfAafDchlQHhmIJkngjNa0ahgXq9FQjKamSiRPDuCBrTzsNVrPmvbAjUIWoA)]

Or by using a conditional with `infer` (where I have to insert a cast)

```
type InferMe<T extends GenericCompany<any>> = T extends GenericCompany<infer R> ? R : never;

function getEmployeeDetails<F extends GenericPerson, T extends GenericCompany<F>>(company: T): InferMe<T>[] {
  return company.employees as InferMe<T>[];
}
```

[[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgBWQZwPbygF4oBvAKCingEMBbCALim2FXgHMBuMgX27NCRYCZOgDCuWmGrwQAHgAaUCAA9gCACbZhiVJhz4AfEVIUoaSdNkA5Oo2asUHbpQhSANrhAQI2JgoBtAF1uPjIBcGgASXgAM2QAWQg5ABVlNU1tOF1xSxl5fMNjYjTVdXgtHVE0CSl8uSd4pCgAJWMAflaoJkQAN2R+WIBXeDRgFHwodghgAFEPLx8AERnqFHdsOQAxdPLK7OqsJDx4ABpKUoyKrJE9Wqt5LaKACgs62SYUgEomGKak1KGYKmShIGZDJAEN4PAB0bjAnm8vig1G0f0SyRSQJCvHC0zmCyRK2Aaw2z3IlGh+Vs9CYAHIFABNABadNOZnhiJ8figATMlAplCFNFpUDpAClcAALeBs-lC6gaDRg7A8ukAGXwGnwcqFUB4ZiC7J4XxhtGoYGezxUXyIxkFFngeHcEBhnnY1phiuVvmwX1C-qAA)]

**Question:** Is there a reason for this? / Is there a way around it without a cast and without forcing the caller to explicitly provide the arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
function getEmployeeDetails<F extends GenericPerson>(company: GenericCompany<F>): F[] {
    return company.employees;
}

getEmployeeDetails({ companyName: 'XYZ', employees: [{ name: 'John', address: 'London' }], })
    .map(x => console.log(x.address)); // property 'address' recognized correctly.
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `F` generic type variable, it can be simplified:

```
const getEmployeeDetails = <T extends GenericCompany<GenericPerson>>(company: T): T['employees'] => {
  return company.employees;
};
```